# I'm getting a "Does not implement IController" error on images and robots.txt in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, routes

I'm getting a strange error on my webserver for seemingly every file but the .aspx files.

Here is an example. Just replace '/robots.txt' with any .jpg name or .gif or whatever and you'll get the idea:

> The controller for path '/robots.txt'
>   was not found or does not implement
>   IController.

I'm sure it's something to do with how I've setup routing but I'm not sure what exactly I need to do about it.

Also, this is a mixed MVC and WebForms site, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you using custom `IControllerFactory`?

Comment: What if you are using an IControllerFactory, what then @DanielA.WhiteZ?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the handler for static files. Just saying.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can ignore robots.txt and all the aspx pages in your routing.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx=@".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*robotstxt}", new {robotstxt=@"(.*/)?robots.txt(/.*)?"});
```

You might want to ignore the favicon too.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new {favicon=@"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?"});
```

You can adjust the regular expression to exclude paths.

Haacked from the [source](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx).

Comment: I like this solution, it sucks I'm going to have to add one for each file type though. .jpg, .png, .gif, .swf, .pdf, etc etc.

Comment: @blesh - are you using a custom `IControllerFactory`?

Comment: No... but looking into it, I think I may start. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Daniel A White - I started using a custom IControllerFactory as part of my implementation for Unity IoC and this error cropped up (it didn't happen prior). Why did this happen?

Comment: hmm none of this explains why this error happens in the first place. For some reason I get it only for one image.. I used to get it for .map files and now just for clear.png. why not for any of the other 100 images?!  this is driving me nuts..

Answer (score 18):

The ignore route given above didn't work for me but I found a similar one that did:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*staticfile}", new { staticfile = @".*\.(css|js|gif|jpg)(/.*)?" });
```

Answer (score 6):

This error could also happen if inside a view in your area, you use the Html.Action helper. This helper will always use the area as a prepend, unless you specifically tell it not to. E.g.,

```
@Html.Action("Main", "Navigation", new { area = string.Empty })
```

Comment: Your answer solved my another problem related to @Html.Action

Answer (score 3):

I found [another solution](http://forums.asp.net/t/1253084.aspx) too... While I don't think I'll use it, it's worth showing here in the answers:

The following should (in theory) ignore looking for controllers for anything with a '.' in it.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },  // Parameter defaults
    new { controller = @"[^\.]*" }                          // Parameter contraints.
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you still have:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

... in your Global.asax.cs?

MVC puts it there by default, and it's supposed to handle this.

If you do, then the problem may be how you're mixing MVC and WebForms.

Comment: And make sure it is at the top!

Comment: I have it... but it's below `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");` is that an issue?

Comment: Yes, I am using MVC and webforms. I have still facing issue. I have many research but not found any solution. Can you help me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when I request resources that did not exist.

Specifically, I was requesting a custom IE css file:

> `<!--[if lt IE 8]>@Styles.Render("~/Content/ie7.css")<![endif]-->`

(These are [condition comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), interpreted by IE)

However, the actual resource existed on ~/Content/ie/ie7.css.

So, without any modifications to the routing, the error was solved by using the correct url of the resource.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why bother with the condition comments if you can detect browser version in a server side @block and just not render the extra styles at all?

Comment: Well, actually I never bothered. The css and most of the mark-up were the work of a team mate. I suppose its just a result of a front-end designer's wish to keep everything under control. Triggered by your remark, I just read on [MSDN - About conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that support has been dropped in IE10 standards mode, so, we'll have to look into this.