# The controller for path icon does not implement IController, Regular expression

Tags: regex, global-asax

I have an exception in project:
The controller for path '/Content/Images/CustomFavicon.ico' was not found or does not implement IController.

I have found answer here: [I'm getting a "Does not implement IController" error on images and robots.txt in MVC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109841/im-getting-a-does-not-implement-icontroller-error-on-images-and-robots-txt-in)

which gives me description of my problem and solution for it.

However I am weak on regular expressions, so have the same problem.
How can i modify this expression to math both paths of icon expression for example below:

```
(/.*)?CustomFavicon.ico?(/.*)
```

if my html link file look

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head id="ctl00_Head1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" HREF="/Content/Images/CustomFavicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" href="/Content/Images/CustomFavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"><title>
   Home Page
  </title></head>
<body>
```

acodring to my test (see below), it finds only one match which also contains html I don't want:

see here my test: http://regexr.com?2tl4a

This is going to be used in my Global.aspx file:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
  //ignore route for ico files
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?CustomFavicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your regex I am not sure what you want to match. I modified it a bit so that the two path are matched.

```
(?:\/.*?)CustomFavicon.ico
```

See [here your modified example](http://regexr.com?2tl4j)

If you want to have this in a capturing group, then put brackets around it, like:

```
((?:\/.*?)CustomFavicon.ico)
```

Comment: i need to add exception to ignore routes for ico files into my global.aspx, see my original post

Comment: @Pavel, I have not realy an idea what the Global.aspx file is good for. My regex is matching the two pathes to the *.ico files. If you need something else to match or not to match, then please specify it that I can improve my regex.

Comment: hi, i will be able to do so in the tuesday, still it match the regex, thank you for that :)