# Robots.txt and SiteMap.xml within MVC 2 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, sitemap, robots.txt

So I have an MVC 2 website online right now. I set up my webmaster account over at google, and they want me to submit the robots.txt and sitemap.xml URL's of my site.

Directions are, "put them in your sites root directory", yeah yeah yeah I know, but this doesn't work with MVC, since everything is based off routing.

Is there a way I can set both these things up so I can access them directly by going like, www.domain.com/robots.txt and www.domain.com/sitemap.xml ?

Both the the files are currently in my root directory, I just don't know how to set it up so I can access them like that using that type of URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this did it :)

[I'm getting a "Does not implement IController" error on images and robots.txt in MVC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109841/im-getting-a-does-not-implement-icontroller-error-on-images-and-robots-txt-in)