# Getting error: The controller for path '/Content/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Please see below the error trace:

> xxx.MvcApplication [(null)] - Application_Error: Unhandled Excpetion:
>   System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path
>   '/Content/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png' was not found or
>   does not implement IController.    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c_*DisplayClass6.b*_2()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust[TResult](Func`1
>   func)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

We already have :

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{allasmx}", new {allasmx=@".*\.asmx(/.*)?"});
```

in global.asax.cs file, however not sure why this error is shown. The image URL is nothing but the image provided by jQuery plugins. Not sure at which event this is getting fired as the error message is from prod log.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at [I'm getting a "Does not implement IController" error on images and robots.txt in MVC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109841/im-getting-a-does-not-implement-icontroller-error-on-images-and-robots-txt-in) as it provides insight and solutions to the problem at hand.

Comment: The solution suggested in the link have been tried but not sure why I am still getting this error.