# elmah error log flooded with Controller path does not found or does not implement IController error after hosting on windows azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

We have hosted our asp.net mvc 5 web application on windows azure server & have implemented elmah for error logging. There are lots of errors like the ones listed below

1. The controller for path '/_tomcat/index.jsp' was not found or does not implement IController.
2. The controller for path '/CluJaNuL/cmd.jsp' was not found or does not implement IController.
3. The controller for path '/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor' was not found or does not implement IController.
4. The controller for path '/manager/html' was not found or does not implement IController.
5. The controller for path '/robots.txt' was not found or does not implement IController.
6. The controller for path '/testproxy.php' was not found or does not implement IController.
7. The controller for path '/wstats/wstats.jsp' was not found or does not implement IController.
8. The controller for path '/zecmd/zecmd.jsp' was not found or does not implement IController.

Our client is accessing this application on a secured Citrix environment on IE11.

There are couple of other clients who are directly accessing the application from an external IP address from a server our own premise & their error log does not contain this error.

Will anybody be able to point out what we are doing wrong with the Azure deployment or is this the crawlers that search engines used to capture the web pages or any kind of attack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting a "Does not implement IController" error on images and robots.txt in MVC2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109841/im-getting-a-does-not-implement-icontroller-error-on-images-and-robots-txt-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. Since your MVC applications are open to the web, various search bots and other types of bots will scan your sites for new pages, vulnerabilities etc. You can either see through those errors or setup an ignore filter with ELMAH as described in the [documentation](https://elmah.github.io/a/error-filtering/).